# I have two datatable in a dataset. I normally log in and out. When I go back in, one of the datatables is empty

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I store user information in the "Users" table.
I keep the barcode information generated by these users in the "Barcode" table.
Each time "Users" content is empty. I couldn't find a solution.
When one of the data tables is deleted, the other works correctly. 
It is more accurate to create a separate dataset.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ulgen_QA_Barcode
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        static UserDataSet db;       
        protected static UserDataSet App
        {
            get
        {
            if (db == null)
            db= new UserDataSet();
            return db;
        }

        }
        string skullanici;
        string spass;
        string slevel;
        int yetki=0;       

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                      
                String fileNameb = string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath);
                if (File.Exists(fileNameb))    
                App.Barcode.ReadXml(fileNameb);
                barcodeBindingSource.DataSource = App.Barcode;

                string fileName = string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath);
                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                App.Users.ReadXml(fileName);
                usersBindingSource.DataSource = App.Users;   
                dataGridView2.DataSource = barcodeBindingSource;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = usersBindingSource;       


            //panel1.Enabled = false;
            //BCode.Enabled = false;
            //BCode.Visible = false;
            //panel3.Enabled = false;
            //panel3.Visible = false;
            //button2.Enabled = false;
            //button2.Visible = false;
            //button3.Enabled = false;
            //button3.Visible = false;
            //button5.Enabled = false;
            //button5.Visible = false;
        }

        private void Kayit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
            usersBindingSource.EndEdit();
            App.Users.AcceptChanges();
            App.Users.WriteXml(string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath));
            panel1.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Mesaj", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                App.Users.RejectChanges();
            }
        }

        private void Degistir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.Focus();
        }

        private void Iptal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            usersBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
            panel1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void Yeni_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                panel1.Enabled = true;
                App.Users.AddUsersRow(App.Users.NewUsersRow());
                usersBindingSource.MoveLast();
                textBox1.Focus();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Mesaj", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                App.Users.RejectChanges();
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Kayıt Silinecek", "Mesaj", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    usersBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
                }
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox4_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

            // ARAMA
            //if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            //{
     //           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text))
     //           {
     //               var query = from o in App.Users
     //                           where o.User == textBox4.Text || o.User.Contains(textBox4.Text)
     //                           select o;
     //               dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
     //           }
     //           else
     //           {
     //               dataGridView1.DataSource = usersBindingSource;
     //           }
            //}
        }

        private void BT_Giris_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Kullanici.Text))
            {
                var query = from o in App.Users
                            where o.User == Kullanici.Text //|| o.User.Contains(Kullanici.Text)
                            select o;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = usersBindingSource;
            }
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                int selectedrowindex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedrowindex];
                // textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["Pass"].Value);
               skullanici = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();               
               spass = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();                
               slevel = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

               if (Kullanici.Text == skullanici & Sifre.Text == spass)
               {
                   label2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

                   if (slevel == "User")
                   {
                       yetki = 1;
                       kullanıcı();
                   }
                   if (slevel == "Admin")
                   {
                       yetki = 2;
                   }

                   if (yetki == 2)
                   {
                       button2.Visible = true;
                       button2.Enabled = true;
                       kullanıcı();
                   }

               }
               else
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("Kullanıcı veya Şifre Hatalı", "Uyarı", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                   skullanici = "";
                   spass = "";
                   slevel = "";
                   Kullanici.Text = "";
                   Sifre.Text = "";
                   label2.Text = "";
                   dataGridView1.DataSource = usersBindingSource;
               }

            }           

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            yetki = 0;
            skullanici = "";
            spass = "";
            slevel = "";
            Kullanici.Text = "";
            Sifre.Text = "";
            label2.Text = "";
            BCode.Visible = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = usersBindingSource;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = barcodeBindingSource;

        }

        void kullanıcı()
        {            
            button5.Visible = true;
            button5.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel3.Visible = true;
            panel3.Enabled = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = usersBindingSource;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = barcodeBindingSource;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox5.Text = BCode.Text;
            textBox6.Text = Kullanici.Text;
            textBox7.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            try
            {
                barcodeBindingSource.EndEdit();
                App.Barcode.AcceptChanges();
                App.Barcode.WriteXml(string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath));                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Mesaj", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                App.Barcode.RejectChanges();

            }
            try
            {
                usersBindingSource.EndEdit();
                App.Users.AcceptChanges();
                App.Users.WriteXml(string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Mesaj", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                App.Users.RejectChanges();
            }          
            string barcode = BCode.Text;            
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(barcode.Length * 40, 150);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                Font oFont = new System.Drawing.Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 14);
                PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                SolidBrush black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush White = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

                graphics.FillRectangle(White, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
                graphics.DrawString ("*" + barcode + "*", oFont, black, point);
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                PictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
                PictureBox1.Height = bitmap.Height;
                PictureBox1.Width = bitmap.Width;
            }         
            }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               // panel1.Enabled = true;
                App.Barcode.AddBarcodeRow(App.Barcode.NewBarcodeRow());
                barcodeBindingSource.MoveLast();
                BCode.Visible = true;
                BCode.Enabled = true;
                BCode.Focus();
                BCode.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmss");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Mesaj", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                App.Barcode.RejectChanges();
            }
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = usersBindingSource;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = barcodeBindingSource;            
            usersBindingSource.EndEdit();
            App.Users.AcceptChanges();
            barcodeBindingSource.EndEdit();
            App.Barcode.AcceptChanges();         
            App.Users.WriteXml(string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath));
            App.Barcode.WriteXml(string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not clear what you are asking. Please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how-to-create-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Your question not clear. So like puzzle. But there is some possible points:

two different db use same file as source is it correct?

```cs
String fileNameb = string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath);
string fileName = string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath);
```

I think your problem here.
Before close program you write

App.Users.WriteXml(string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath));

and

App.Barcode.WriteXml(string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath));

it will overwrite your destination file I think.

You can use two different destination file.

Wrong:

```cs
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = usersBindingSource;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = barcodeBindingSource;            
            usersBindingSource.EndEdit();
            App.Users.AcceptChanges();
            barcodeBindingSource.EndEdit();
            App.Barcode.AcceptChanges();         
            App.Users.WriteXml(string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath));
            App.Barcode.WriteXml(string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath));
        }
```

Correct:

```cs
....
String fileNameb = string.Format("{0}//barcodedata.dat", Application.StartupPath);
string fileName = string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath);
....
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = usersBindingSource;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = barcodeBindingSource;            
            usersBindingSource.EndEdit();
            App.Users.AcceptChanges();
            barcodeBindingSource.EndEdit();
            App.Barcode.AcceptChanges();         
            App.Users.WriteXml(string.Format("{0}//userdata.dat", Application.StartupPath));
            App.Barcode.WriteXml(string.Format("{0}//barcodedata.dat", Application.StartupPath));
        }
```